# When is Log4Net configured?

Tags: c#, log4net, logging

Given that you have

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

in your AssemblyInfo.cs file, when is Log4Net configured? Is it at the application start or when you use a logger for the first time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The config file is used when you cause a call to the `LoggerManager` class. This is usually caused by calling LogManager.GetLogger.

See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfiguratorAttribute.html for more details; specifically the note:

> Log4net will only look for assembly
>   level configuration attributes once.
>   When using the log4net assembly level
>   attributes to control the
>   configuration of log4net you must
>   ensure that the first call to any of
>   the LoggerManager methods is made from
>   the assembly with the configuration
>   attributes.

Answer (score 3):

A quote from the Apache log4net site:

> Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the calling assembly to be read and processed. Therefore it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Here is a good article on how to make sure the configuration is set up and run properly:
http://www.fooji.net/blog/post/2010/04/27/logging-log4net-e28093-part-iii.aspx

Basically, you need to either make a logging call (which configures log4net if it isn't already configured) or utilize the DOMConfigurator to manually configure log4net.

Comment: Second link is broken.